# How to write a simple java program to exchange a authorization code to a ID token in Keycloak

Tags: java, keycloak

My Java client can receives authorisation code in the redirect URL when the user is validated in Keycloak.

Now I want to use this authorisation code to get the ID token from Keycloak(in a back channel).

Answer (score 0):

In the java client we usually use the hit post keycloak api with the auth code to get the token ID

```
        String keycloakUrl = "https://your-keycloak-url/auth/realms/your-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token";
    String clientId = "your-client-id";
    String clientSecret = "your-client-secret";
    String redirectUri = "your-redirect-uri";
    String authorizationCode = "the-authorization-code";
```

Am I understand your question correctly ?